# StringIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, android, string

Hi I was just using stringbuilder to obtain certain part of the string using substring(int start, int end).. but I'm having this error

```
08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; regionStart=0; regionLength=4

08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.startEndAndLength(AbstractStringBuilder.java:216)

08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:625)

08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:44)

08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313):    at com.example.john.Contact.getAllCallLogs(Contact.java:196)

08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313):    at com.example.john.Contact.onCreate(Contact.java:49)

08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)

08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)

08-17 20:27:40.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15313):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
```

And this is how i simply implement:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(phoneNumber);
          String fourth = str.substring(0, 4);
```

I just want to obtain the first 4 character of my phoneNumber string

Comment: What is the phone number?

Comment: @ihsan phoneNumber is a string type.

Comment: @RieJack what is the value of phone number(is it 1234? for example)

Comment: I'm betting that phoneNumber is a zero-length string.

Comment: @kiheru substring(int start, int end) where start is inclusive and end is exclusive..so only the first 4..

Comment: use String fourth = str.substring(0, 3);

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I was very careless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to obtain the first 4 string of my phoneNumber string

But your number has length lower than 4. If you want to get first four numbers you need to add simple condition:

```
if (str.length() > 4) {
   // do your work
}
```

Don't forget that substring begins at the specified start and extends to the character at index end - 1.

Comment: Thanks, I was very careless!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the substring() method but you no   has length lower than 4 ,so if you want to get only four number use the following code.

Ex:

```
   class  SubString
      {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(phoneNumber);
    if(str.length()>4){
    System.out.println(str.substring(0,4));
    }
     }
    }
```